# How to do muted / grayed text in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

This seems to exist in most UI frameworks, in a way that will work with both light and dark themes, but it seems to be absent here.

Currently I've resorted to doing:

`val Muted = Color.LightGray`

and importing that elsewhere, but it looks bad on light themes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose has `ContentAlpha.medium`, that is used, as the name suggests, to display a color as muted.

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it, but I usually use it like this:

```
Text(
    text = myText,
    color = when {
        isEnabled -> MaterialTheme.colors.myColor
        else -> MaterialTheme.colors.myColor.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium)
    }
)
```

You could abstract it into a extension field and add it to your themes file:

```
val Color.muted get() = this.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium)
```

And use it like this:

```
color = when {
    isEnabled -> MaterialTheme.colors.myColor
    else -> MaterialTheme.colors.myColor.muted
```

Comment: This is close, seems like I can do `val Color.disabled @Composable get() = this.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)`, but unfortunately its a really dark gray, too dark for the text I need. Is there some way to choose a muted color that would work for both light and dark themes?

Comment: @thouliha It's strange, `ContentAlpha.disabled` is contrast-conscious, so it should work in both dark and light themes. But you could tweak this `Color.disabled` field with an if statement checking if the system is in the dark theme, with `isSystemInDarkTheme()`, and set a different `alpha` based on it. Maybe some testing will be needed on your part to see which `alpha` works better in each theme.

Comment: Thanks, using this worked, but using ContentAlpha.medium looked better than ContentAlpha.disabled!

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `Color.luminance()` value of the background color and choose the Grayscale color of the text in case of dynamic theming.
2. Using `isSystemInDarkTheme()` to pick color in combination with `contentColorFor()`, when we have fixed theming system,